# SQL NOT EXISTS too slow on OpenQuery

Tags: sql-server

I currently use NOT EXISTS to copy data from a db2 remote server to keep my local table updated. This procedure is executed every week only in 1 day. Problem is that it takes over than 40s to execute it if it's not cached.

Basically i need to insert records by 2 columns, References and UAP ( Production unit) where 1 Reference can have many UAP's. I assume the query becomes slower because of both conditions on the where clause.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE CopyReferenciasFromPDP
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @NumTurnos int, 
            @NumPab int,
            @AlcanceAbastecimento int,
            @QtdMin int,
            @QtdMax int

    SET @NumTurnos = 3
    SET @NumPab = 6
    SET @AlcanceAbastecimento = 3
    SET @QtdMin = 3
    SET @QtdMax = 12

    INSERT INTO Parametros  
    SELECT
        Referencia,     
        UAP,
        @NumTurnos AS NumTurnos,
        @NumPab AS NumPAB,
        @AlcanceAbastecimento AS AlcanceAbastecimento,
        @QtdMin AS QtdMin,
        @QtdMax AS QtdMax
    FROM OPENQUERY(MACPAC, 
        'SELECT 
            A.RH6001 as Referencia, 
            A.RH6002 as UAP
        FROM AUTO.D805DATPOR.TRP060H AS A       
        WHERE (A.RH6001 Not Like ''FS%'')
        AND A.RH6030 <> 0') M
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS 
        ( 
            SELECT * FROM Parametros P  
            WHERE M.Referencia = P.Referencia 
            AND M.UAP = P.UAP 
        )

END
```

How can i increase performance ? Or is there any faster alternatives to where not exists?

Also the openquery returns an average of 2k records weekly, most records are always the same though.

**FINAL RESULT**

Here is the final solution. I used a table variable as suggested by @scsimon

```
ALTER PROCEDURE CopyReferenciasFromPDP
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @NumTurnos INT, 
            @NumPab INT,
            @AlcanceAbastecimento INT,
            @QtdMin INT,
            @QtdMax INT

    SET @NumTurnos = 3
    SET @NumPab = 6
    SET @AlcanceAbastecimento = 3
    SET @QtdMin = 3
    SET @QtdMax = 12

    CREATE TABLE #tempTable 
    (
        Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
        Referencia VARCHAR(15),
        UAP NVARCHAR(20),
        NumTurnos INT,
        NumPab INT,
        AlcanceAbastecimento INT,
        QtdMin INT,
        QtdMax INT
        UNIQUE (Id)
    )

    INSERT INTO #tempTable  
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Referencia ASC),
        Referencia,     
        UAP,
        @NumTurnos AS NumTurnos,
        @NumPab AS NumPAB,
        @AlcanceAbastecimento AS AlcanceAbastecimento,
        @QtdMin AS QtdMin,
        @QtdMax AS QtdMax
    FROM OPENQUERY(MACPAC, 
        'SELECT 
            A.RH6001 as Referencia, 
            A.RH6002 as UAP
        FROM AUTO.D805DATPOR.TRP060H AS A       
        WHERE (A.RH6001 Not Like ''FS%'')
        AND A.RH6030 <> 0') 


    INSERT INTO 
        Parametros
    SELECT 
        Referencia, 
        UAP,        
        NumTurnos,
        NumPab,
        AlcanceAbastecimento,
        QtdMin,
        QtdMax
    FROM 
        #tempTable M
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS 
        ( 
            SELECT * FROM Parametros P  
            WHERE M.Referencia = P.Referencia 
            AND M.UAP = P.UAP
        )

    DROP TABLE #tempTable
END
```

**EDIT**

Changed table variable to temp table

Comment: I'd start by staging the results of your `OPENQUERY` into a `#tempTable` and then `SELECT` from your `#tempTable` with your `NOT EXISTS` clause.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by staging?

Comment: `SELECT 
            A.RH6001 as Referencia, 
            A.RH6002 as UAP
           into #myTemp
        FROM AUTO.D805DATPOR.TRP060H AS A       
        WHERE (A.RH6001 Not Like 'FS%')
        AND A.RH6030 <> 0` and then... `insert into Parametros select ... from #myTemp where not exists...` The idea is to pull the data from the AUTO server into your current server before working with it.

Comment: Oh I see, I suppose the subquery on the where clause makes another roundtrip to remote server

Comment: You can also apply indexes to `#tempTables` to speed things up. Sometimes they help, sometimes they don't. It all depends... but the option is there too.

Comment: Thanks alot, my query is so much faster now! I will use this approach with indexes on future queries :)

Comment: So, Table Variables won't perform as well as temp tables generally speaking. This is due to a few things, but notably SQL Server will only ever think your table variable has a single row, which can mess up your resource allocations and estimates. [see more here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2825/sql-server-temp-table-vs-table-variable-performance-testing/) among other places. just a heads up.

Comment: I searched about temp tables vs table variables and i assumed it only mattered which one would do the job much easier. I tried avoid temp table so i didn't need to dispose it at the end

Comment: Your temp table is disposed of after you connection is closed... or you can drop it explicitly. Either way, definitely worth it :)